# What are the rules to be aware of on a road with a sign that indicates rocks might fall?

Tags: legal, safety, road-signs

[image]

I'm from Flanders and I don't have a driver's license. These signs are rather rare in Flanders, but I see them frequently as a passenger alongside the Spanish coast, in the Valencia province.

The thing I don't understand: what does this sign mean? That there might be rocks falling on your car? You don't know when they're going to fall, so you can't adjust your speed for it. Rocks might lie on the road? You'll see that anyway.

How should you adjust your behavior around these signs?

Comment: "Rocks might lie on the road? You'll see that anyway."  you'd be surprised by what some people won't see if they aren't looking for it. And I am not even excluding myself here - I once almost drove into a rock because I did not expect one to just lie on the street.

Comment: I think the idea is to be aware that rocks may be lieing ont he road, and be prepared for obstructions when cornering/cresting/etc

Comment: The sign is an advisory, so there are no 'rules' to follow. But CMaster is right. I used to wonder about that too.

Comment: I've always assumed this meant to slow down enough so that if you do encounter a rock on the road, you can stop before you hit it.

Comment: See also the discussion starting with [this post](//groups.google.com/d/msg/alt.usage.english/PAZ4m_dGecc/kWR7lStDf9sJ).

Comment: Lots of good answers, but think of it as similar to warnings of children in the area. The goal is to alert you to less common hazards that could result in the need for rapid maneuvering on your part or that of other drivers.

Comment: In my country it means caution: spontaneous crust-first pizza disintegration area. Generally you should finish your pizza first, or at least eat it defensively and maintain awareness of the crust state. Pizza delivery drivers are encouraged to find an alternate route.

Comment: Its much more about not stopping there, not conducting stationary activities, and being aware in the event of a traffic jam that crosses the area than trying to induce drivers quaff a "+10 to rock avoidance potion".

Comment: I personally feel all of the above to be valid answers. Unstable mountains can be a huge risk. Being relatively rare though, thankfully, one can become complacent. I always keep my eyes peeled! I happened to see the questioner is from Flanders. Personally I would rather take my chances with a few stray boulders, indeed a small unstable mountain, than ever driving in Belgium! Happy Motoring!

Comment: I agree with the other answers. But, I would also like to add that the sign also implies that the driver should take caution when driving in the area the sign indicated in case of falling rocks a

Comment: Driving with no driver's license?

Comment: @Taladris the reason I say I don't have a driver's license is to make clear that I don't know what many signs mean.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: thanks for answering. Having a driving license is much more than just knowing the signs.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Basically it is a warning of the potential for rock falls.  Two warnings built into one, 1) rocks could being falling into your path or on your vehicle 2) rocks could have fallen and maybe on the roadway ahead.

Your actions should be to watch not only the normal driving issues, but also keep your eyes out for rocks that maybe be present on the roadway or falling.  If the road is winding with short vision distances, then slowing down is warranted.

Comment: ...and 3) rocks might be in the path of *oncoming traffic*. I narrowly missed a head-on collision one time when a huge speeding truck going the opposite direction drove over a rock in the road while cornering, causing it to slip across into my lane almost head-on into the vehicle I was in. Luckily my driver saw this coming (or, had amazing reflexes!) and swerved just in time to avoid it

Comment: Edited number 2 to better describe what I meant.

Answer (score 27):

I have to add another very important point that is not listed so far: When you see this sign you should also avoid any unnecessary stops to decrease the chances to bet hit by rocks. This is in particular the case when you see this sign on hiking paths in the mountains. The sign is not only used on roads but also paths. It's not really a law though, but you should really follow this recommendation.

Here is a good example with text in English, German and French:

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's an important point (very or otherwise), it's a different meaning for this sign in a different context (namely when you are hiking, on foot). The OP has no reason to be wary of stops when driving, in this context, it's really about rocks lying on the road.

Comment: I don't agree. I wouldn't park my car on a road that has this sign. You dramatically increase the chances that your car gets hit by a rock. Granted, in a car it might probably not be deadly, but still it will cost you at least a lot of money.

Comment: And for example these rocks can easily kill you, even if you're in a car: http://www.tagblatt.ch/storage/scl/online/unfaelleverbrechen/2200872_m3w560h330q75v42123_Wildhaus.jpg?version=1407836283

Comment: Maybe, but I objected to the notion that you should not *stop*, nobody mentioned parking because it's a bit silly. I have never seen an area where that's really a serious issue, this sign simply does not occur in places where you would let your car for a long time.

Comment: But the most important point is that it's confusing to conflate both signs. When hiking, rocks on the ground are a non-issue and rocks falling (especially because someone in front of you moved them) is what the sign is about. By contrast, on mountain roads, falling rocks are still very rare (otherwise the road would have to be closed and protected) and the sign is about stones lying on the ground.

Comment: And do the stones grow on the ground? No, they have to fall down, otherwise there wouldn't be any stones on the road in the first place.

Comment: You're being disingenuous. Of course they have to be falling but there was a serious risk or large rocks falling, you could not keep the road open and be happy by putting a sign! It's not what it is about. The problem is that this confusion leads to the silly advice someone else posted about driving quicker… It's very important to understand that we are dealing with two different meanings of the sign, which call for different behaviours.

Comment: I think this is _precisely_ the purpose of the sign. It means "get on with it, lest you end up crushed under a boulder".

Comment: @Relaxed I think the answer's point is obvious, and far from disingenuous. It's basic maths. For any given interval of time there is some probability of a rock falling on your car. The higher the multiple of that interval that you spend in that area, the higher the chance of you being hit. The absolute value of the probability (whether low or high) is irrelevant. There is no distinction between parking and stopping - parking is merely a longer form of stopping.

Comment: @JBentley The answer's point is indeed obvious. It's also wrong. The absolute value of the probability is very relevant, the notion that any increase matters, no matter how small is misleading when thinking about risk, leading directly to the dangerous idea that you should speed up, which is definitely not the intent of the sign when it's placed on a road. That's a very important point, if you want more details, you can see the discussion about my answer.

Comment: (What I called disingenuous was merely the last comment because in light of this other discussion, my point should be clear to the OP by now. It's silly to suppose I don't know stones have to fall from somewhere and that it's just a matter of common sense. The fact that it seems obvious to so many people – cf. the votes and comments like that of LightnessRacesinOrbit – just shows how important it is to think clearly about this because the real intent of the sign is far from trivial.)

Comment: @Relaxed But this answer doesn't say anything about dangerously *speeding up*. Doing so would of course create additional risks of it's own. This answer merely suggests that you should "avoid any unnecessary stops", which is a perfectly reasonable response, and does in fact lower your risks, without any downside.

Comment: @JBentley Sure, but that has already been discussed at length. Even if the answer itself does not explicitly advocate speeding up, the problem is that the OP's logic and comments do lead to this dangerous conclusion. And it's in any case a mistake to argue it's “a very important point”, that's where the absolute value of the probability comes in and simplistic mathematical arguments do not cut it. The only very important point lost in this discussion is that the road sign, unlike the one pictured in the answer, is really about something else entirely, namely stones lying on the ground.

Comment: @Relaxed I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. I never said you should speed up. I said you should avoid unnecessary stops.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException That's where you are being disingenuous again. You wrote “The point of the sign is that you be extra careful and in particular walk through the section as fast as possible to minimize the risk. **And I say at least to a certain extend this is also true for roads.** You just shouldn't stop on roads like this to minimize the time you spend in the potentially dangerous area to minimize the risk to get hit by rocks falling down on the road.” in a comment to my answer.

Comment: That's what I object to, I explained at length why I think it's wrong and why I think your answer just furthers this confusion. You did nothing to clarify either your answer or your position in this respect. The most important point is that stops do not matter for the same reason than speeding up is not a good idea.

Comment: There are very few places on roads where rocks fall with such regularity that parking is a significant danger; the risk is almost always *fallen rocks*.  The chance of seeing a fallen rock is roughly 24 hours worth of rock falls (presuming relatively rapid cleanup) along the *entire length* of the road.  And even then, the odds are going to be single digit percentages or less (I have seen many warning signs, and never actual rocks).  In comparison, one car-size spot for even a few hours is going to be minuscule.

Comment: In some countries where this kind of sign is common, the road is very twisty, with many(sometimes effectively all) blind corners. Speeding up to avoid falling rocks in this situation quite significantly increases the risks of a fatal accident due to already fallen rocks hidden by a blind corner.

Answer (score 13):

This signal is just a warning sign. It's information about a possible danger.
You're not supposed to do anything in particular as rule. You should assume a defensive position against this event though. Whatever that means it's up to you. Locals may know about it, but you, that come from a flat land, wouldn't even suspect. There are many of these signs, that I learned in driving school, and I never saw in real life. Not all dangers are everywhere. Sometimes, when travelling one pops.

You might think it's very useless but take this example:

Imagine I aproach you and I slap you by surprise in the face. What would your reaction be? You would be completly surprised - you could run away afraid or you could even react in surprise and do the same. But I did slap you. Or maybe I just caught a mutant bug in your face that was about to kill you. You don't know!

Now, imagine someone warns you I can slap and I approach you with the same intention? what would you do? you would be prepared and could react properly!

It's the same here. You will have a more defensive attitude towards falling rocks or rocks on the road. You should assume both situations are possible. If at night, with wind or rain you will probably want to drive slower or you might even drive at the same speed if confident enough, but you will be aware of the rocks. If some fall or you hit one with your car you know what happened and will probably react in a more appropriate way. If caught by surprise you could react in unexpected ways and cause a larger accident by driving off road or against another car.

**To conclude:** this kind of information is very important to make you aware of possible dangers that otherwise you wouldn't know of. You should than adapt your behaviour accordingly to the risk, considering external factors as well like wind, rain, visibility and traffic conditions, but it's up to you to decide.

If you're puzzled with that sign you should look at this one, it's my favorite:

[image: various dangers]

This is also a danger sign, and basically means "various dangers". You should basically prepare... anything can happen! :)

Comment: I wonder how you imagine a "defensive posture" against falling boulders to look?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It depends on the road and local conditions. There is no unique answer and thats why the code does not specify it. Anyway if the rocks are that big and the risk so eminent the road should be closed!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I don’t know a defense against *falling* rocks, but against the risk of *fallen* rocks in the road, I would just drive a little extra-cautiously.

Answer (score 6):

Rocks normally fall onto a road in two situations:

1. A freeze-thaw or heat/cool cycle has forced the rock out of place, causing it to fall.
2. Rain or flowing water has washed away dirt supporting the rock.

Because of this, most rockfalls occur during the early morning or during/just after rainstorms, particularly during the cooler months.  If you're driving during a sunny summer afternoon, there's no real risk.  On the other hand, during a rainy fall morning, you should slow down and keep an eye out for rocks lying in the road (I once encountered a half-ton boulder under these conditions).  In either case, the odds of being struck by a falling rock are very low.

Comment: +1 especially for the last sentence as it seems there is a lot of confusion about this.

Comment: Sorry but the risk of fallen rocks still being in the road is very real at ANY time of day.  To assume they only are present under certain conditions or time of day is asking for trouble.

Comment: @Tom: Mark has not stated that the risk is absent at particular times. His description is very accurate. Erosion is a geological process that obeys the laws of physics, not an unknowable risk that requires equal precautions under all conditions.

Comment: @BenCrowell - "If you're driving during a sunny summer afternoon, there's no real risk" - that sounds to me like he is saying risk is absent.  And I never disputed his explanation as to why rocks fall, I have known that to be a reason most of my adult life. But as someone who frequently travels by road in the mountains, all over the world, I know that rocks can be present without warning even on sunny afternoons.  And to pooh pooh a warning is a sign of an immature driver.

Comment: @Tom, driving during a sunny summer afternoon, you can also encounter a broken-down car, wildlife, or other obstacles in the road.  The odds of encountering a fallen rock in these conditions is low enough that you don't need to take unusual precautions.

Comment: @mark - ok fine I bow to the expert. But I will continue to drive more cautiously because my 40 years of driving in mountains have taught me so.  I hope you have good insurance.

Answer (score 4):

The German road code just specifies it as a warning sign. [Source](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bundesrecht/stvo_2013/gesamt.pdf) (the sign is called "Steinschlag")

That means there are no specific rules attached to this sign, but in the interest of their own safety, people should pay extra attention. The general road code already specifies that people have to drive carefully, the signs in that list are just reminders, drawing special attention to road conditions.

Specifically, Steinschlag is not listed in [Anlage 1, StVO §40](http://www.dvr.de/betriebe_bg/daten/stvo/anlage1.htm) which further specifies some warning signs, nor Anlage 2 to 4, where signs having an effect on road rules are listed.

I can find no indication that this is different in Spain, but I'm also not Spanish. Not all traffic signs in the EU mean the same thing when it comes to road rules.

Comment: This probably goes too much into individual situations and clauses, but in case your car gets damaged by either a rock falling on you or you driving into a big rock, does this warning sign have any effect on how your insurance will handle paying the damage?

Comment: I couldn't find any indication for that for Germany, but here we also use "steinschlag" as the term for when a small stone breaks the glass of your windshield, so searching is not that easy

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell: Yes, it's about rocks lying on the road and no, you might not always see them, especially on mountain roads with many bends. So it's a warning to adjust your speed (i.e. drive more slowly) and be generally alert in places where the risk is higher. As someone who has a lot of experience driving in mountain areas, I can tell you that it *is* useful.

The Vienna convention on road signs and signals describes the sign thusly:

> 11. Falling rocks
>
> Warning of a section of road on which there is danger from falling rocks and the consequent presence of rocks on the carriageway shall be given […]

Also, to clarify: It's not mainly about huge rocks blocking the road and stopping your car but simply stones that are big enough to cause some damage or prompt you to make a dangerous manoeuvre if you see them too late.

Incidentally, because there seems to be a lot of confusion about this in the comments and some of the answers, it's easy to realise that the sign is mainly about rocks lying on the ground. Any falling rock will represent a danger for a few seconds and then lie there for hours if not days, and many more motorists will be exposed to it lying on the road rather than falling.

If there were so many rocks falling that spending a few extra minutes in the area would matter, the road would be extremely unsafe and literally covered in stones to the point that is is not usable. As @Mark aptly put it in his answer, “the odds of being struck by a falling rock are very low”. Speeding up to reduce that risk is a very bad idea, **you should slow down**.